# Protecting video being from downloaded

Tags: php, protection, streaming

First of all I know that I can't protect it completely but can you give me any tips to make it as secure as possible? And second thing I plan to store videos in seperate dedicated server and is it possible to protect it's actual location 100%? In other words even if user will be able to download can I hide servers ip and etc.?
Website is running on php.

Comment: If you find a method that 100% stop videos being downloaded then be sure to tell Netflix, iTunes, Sky Now and YouTube because your become one wearthie  person ~ no 100% method exists. You can however protect the locations.

Answer (score 2):

Use **temporary resource URLs** that only work once. Have the server generate unique URLs that can only be used once and only be generated by using the player on the intended player page.

For more information, see Stack Overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But lets assume user goes around and downloads the video will he be able to locate actual server? Website is being hosted elsewhere

Comment: @Edgaras As w3d mentioned, use an intermediary server to hide the origin.

Answer (score 2):

> And second thing I plan to store videos in seperate dedicated server and is it possible to protect it's actual location?

Following on from grgarside's answer... the client would make a request to the first server. The first server then makes the request to the separate media server and returns the response to the client. The client at no point connects directly with the media server, so is unaware of its existence (IP address, etc.)